# The fileserver "foo" has closed down. (Netatalk)

Tags: linux, macos, netatalk

I had intermittent disconnects from my netatalk fileserver, especially under i/o load.
See below for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A netatalk upgrade solved it for me, it's a known problem with older versions.

If you see similar problems then try upgrading your netatalk to at least **v2.1.3**.